# Filter out all but one duplicate row in SQL based on a matching key

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to filter out duplicate entries (create a view) based on a key in a table.
Consider the table below

[image]

I want to filter out all but one duplicate records based on EmployeeID. It doesn't matter which record is retained, although it would be nice to have a mechanism to specify a whereClause on it too. The target view looks like this

[image]

I tried using a query based on partition by however I can't quite get my result right.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A key is not "unique" in a table if it has duplicate values.

Comment: Woops, my bad I'll fix the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by employeeid order by employeeid) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Many thanks! works nicely. Had to make a minor edit: it should be partition by instead of partition employeeid - I'll edit the post and accept the answer